# C# Dynamics CRM FilterExpression EntityReference

Tags: c#, reference, filter, entity, dynamics-crm

I am trying to build a FilterExpression with a Lookup value. I have tried passing an EntityReference and a Guid. The EntityReference resulted in a runtime error, whereas the Guid resulted in nothing being returned (the EntityCollection is empty, although I know for sure that at least one entity should be returned). What am I doing wrong?

```
FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("referenced_entity", ConditionOperator.Equal, referencedEntityGuid));

retrieveRequest.Query = new QueryExpression
{
    Criteria = filter,
    EntityName = "my_entity",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new[] { "referenced_entity", "a_property", "another_property" })
};
```

I would like to note that `referencedEntityGuid` is an instance of Guid (obviously) and that when I deactivate the filter, the return type of the `referenced_entity`-property is `EntityReference`. Additionally, `TotalRecordCount` equals -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Guid` should be fine - are you sure that your Guid *value* is correct?

Comment: Oh, damn, I was only checking during the first iteration. Thanks!

Comment: ;-) No worries - we all do it!